# Ant task wsgen fails with JDK11

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, java-11

I have a ant wsgen task defined to create artifacts for an JAX-WS deployment.

It was working fine with Java8 and fails with Java11. No info to debug further just outputs "wsgen error"

Given below is my usecase:

```
build.gradle

configurations {
    jaxws
}

dependencies {
project.dependencies.jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.2.10'
}

ant.taskdef(name: 'wsgen', classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen', classpath: project.configurations.jaxws.asPath)

       webServices.each { service ->
            ant.wsgen(
                keep: true,
                destdir: <dest dir with .class files>,
                sourcedestdir: <src dir with .java files>,
                resourcedestdir: < wsdlDir >,
                genwsdl: 'true',
                classpath:  <dest dir with .class files>,
                protocol: 'Xsoap1.2',
                extension: 'true',
                inlineSchemas: 'true',
                sei: 'com.org.jaxws.sampleService1,
                verbose: 'true'
            )
}
```

```
SampleService1.java

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.jws.WebService;


@WebService(portName = "TestPort")

public class sampleService1 {
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String str) {
    
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      
    output.append("hello");
    return output.toString();
    }
}
```

how do i make this code work for Java11, please suggest.

Comment: Probably a good idea to start the Ant task from the command line and post the results here. What does `ant -p` show in the same directory as your build.xml?